# Where is the keystore?

Tags: java, android, rsa, keystore

I am currently storing a RSA key in my android application, it is to be used for in app encryption of user app data.

I generate the key and store it saving it as a file in the keys directory like so:

```
public RSA(char[] password) throws Exception
{
    private static final String filePath =   System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/keys/";
    mCurrentPassword = password;
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    File possibleKeyFile = new File(filePath + "/" + keyAlias);
    //FileInputStream keyFile = new FileInputStream(filePath + "/" + keyAlias);

    if(!possibleKeyFile.exists()) //if keystore is empty, create a key
    {
        mCurrentCertificate = generateCert();
        //Store the new keypair
        ks.load(null, password);

        KeyStore.ProtectionParameter protParam =
                new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(password);

        java.security.cert.Certificate[] myCert =
                new java.security.cert.Certificate[] {
                        (java.security.cert.Certificate) mCurrentCertificate
                };

        KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry pkEntry =
                new KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry(mCurrentRSAKeyPair.getPrivate(),
                        myCert);

        ks.setEntry(keyAlias, pkEntry, protParam);
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File(filePath + "/" + keyAlias));

        ks.store(os , password);

    }
    else
    {
        //retrieve keypair and assign it to mCurrentKeyPair
        mCurrentRSAKeyPair = getKey(keyAlias, password);
    }
}
```

When I go to retrieve the keystore on my android in debug mode I get an error stating the file does not exist (invalid directory). I am wondering where the key is actually stored if the storing path is set as that?

code to retrieve keypair:

```
private static KeyPair getKey(String alias, char[] password) throws Exception
{
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    FileInputStream keyFile = new FileInputStream(filePath + "/" + alias);
    ks.load(keyFile, password);

    KeyStore.ProtectionParameter protParam =
            new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(password);

    KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry privateKeyEntry =
            (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) ks.getEntry(alias, protParam);
    RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) privateKeyEntry.getPrivateKey();
    //get public key from private key
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    RSAPrivateKeySpec priv = kf.getKeySpec(privateKey, RSAPrivateKeySpec.class);
    RSAPublicKeySpec keySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(priv.getModulus(), BigInteger.valueOf(65537));
    PublicKey publicKey = kf.generatePublic(keySpec);

    KeyPair kp = new KeyPair(publicKey, privateKey);

    return kp;
}
```

Comment: What is filePath set to?  That is what you are storing the key to

Answer (score 0):

```
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File(filePath + "/" + keyAlias));
```

Before you execute this line you should execute this one:

```
filePath.mkdirs();
```

At present it is possible that the directory 'keys' doesn't exist, and you aren't doing anything about ensuring that it does.

You also need to close the output stream after storing the keystore. It appears that you're also ignoring an `IOException` or `FileNotFoundException` somewhere.

Comment: Hi, the path is already created and it is failing on the retrieval of the keystore not the creation of the keystore. Cheers

Comment: So `alias` doesn't have the same value as when you created it. Of course you don't need `alias` as part of the filename at all, as keystores can contain multiple aliases. You could just use a fixed filename, e.g. `System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/.keystore"`. And also of course if you already have the keypair and certificate why do you need the keystore file at all?

Comment: Hi, I need the keystore so that I can keep the same keypair and certificate everytime I reload the app instead of wiping the data and regenerating it each time

Comment: The file cannot be found despite the directory being the same for storage and retrieval